# 2D Character is sticking to walls in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d-games

It started happening after I wrote the script for dashing. Now, whenever I dash into walls, my character gets stuck to that wall. If I dash towards the roof, then I can walk on the roof for example. Also, when I dash next to a wall / on the floor, it never stops dashing after a single press. Any help will be appreciated, thanks.
The code below is the dashing script, if needed I can post the variables set and my character controller script too.

```
void Start()
    {
        _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        dashTime = baseDashTime;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(feet.position, checkRadius, checkGround);

        if(isGrounded == true)
        {
            dashTime = baseDashTime;
        }
        if (direction == 0)
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) && (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift)))
            {
                direction = 1;
            }
            else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) && (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift)))
            {
                direction = 2;
            }
            else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) && (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift)))
            {
                direction = 3;
            }
            else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) && (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift)))
            {
                direction = 4;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (dashTime <= 0)
            {
                direction = 0;
                _rigidbody.velocity = Vector2.zero;
            }
            else
            {
                dashTime -= Time.deltaTime;
                if (direction == 1)
                {
                    _rigidbody.velocity = Vector2.up * dashSpeed;
                }
                else if (direction == 2)
                {
                    _rigidbody.velocity = Vector2.left * dashSpeed;
                }
                else if (direction == 3)
                {
                    _rigidbody.velocity = Vector2.down * dashSpeed;
                }
                else if (direction == 4)
                {
                    _rigidbody.velocity = Vector2.right * dashSpeed;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have this statement in the update function. When you dash on the ground, im guessing IsGrounded will stay true, so the player will keep dashing forever. This is probably what causes the player to be stuck.

```
 if(isGrounded == true)
    {
        dashTime = baseDashTime;
    }
```

Comment: Yeah that appears to be the case, so how can I put a cooldown on my dash? I wrote this to make sure people couldn't dash unlimited at first.

Comment: You could put `dashTime = baseDashTime;` in the `if(dashTime < 0)`. This would reset the time after the player has finished dashing. If you want the player to only dash on the ground you can put isGrounded _within_ the `if(direction ==0)`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I didn't have internet connection for a while so couldn't respond, sorry. Now the character dashes indefinitely :'). I tried implementing a counter, and now I can't dash and jump, at all. This is the code. Funny thing is, jumping isn't even implemented in this script. (I can't post it here so I'll post it as another answer.)

Comment: I looked into your script and found a few errors. First, your `while(dashCounter > 0)
    {
        dashCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
        direction = 0;
        _rigidbody.velocity = Vector2.zero;
    }` will almost always run as when it finishes, the counter is reset after one iteration of the if else loop. Reset the dash counter in the `else if(dashCounter ==0) statement. Note: your character can't move/jump/dash as your while loop always sets the player's velocity to 0